# Proxy server (as a security measure for a home IP camera) on a single board computer

Tags: security, ip-camera

Background -

Assuming that an IP camera UI is a small (usually non-secure) web application that is delivered over http. 
My goal is to proxy the access to that UI and to implement some security measures on that proxy. Once done, the user is defined as "friendly" and would be re-directed to the actual IP camera UI with further proxying of the http transactions only for a basic session validation purposes.
This is for home use only and need to handle max 3~5 simultaneous users.

Questions -

I'm thinking of using mod_perl and Apache for the job cause this is what I know best.
I'm also thinking of implementing this on a single board computer.
I've also read about folks using ModSecurity along with mod_perl. Which sounds like a great plus for my cause.

Having never worked with a single board computer - I have no idea if this is even feasible.

Your thoughts/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: Is it feasible running mod_perl and Apache and possibly ModSecurity on a single board computer like say Raspberry PI or an equivalent? Will this setup be able handling few simultaneous connections or do I need a stronger hardware platform?

Comment: Will this setup handle well the video streaming or is it likely to create a lag?

Comment: What's wrong with IP camera in first place? Many support password protection, some support HTTPS too. You are unlikely to proxy the payload feed (unless it is HTTP based) easily. Hence, the whole approach seems to be meaningless. Instead, just choose the right camera with password protection right there on it.

Comment: The security measures that I'd like to implement on that proxy are not trivial and are not available on a day-to-day IP device of any kind. For an example: GEO location based client filtering, bot detection etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apache with C module can handle it no problem, Apache with mod perl without tooo much crypto probably also. But If you want to use geo location etc. you will need some power (cpu) and if you have that it won't matter which technology you pick it will probably handle it. BTW  Insetad of mod security and additionaly load apache you can use snort.

Comment: Will Apache handle RTSP authentication as well?

Comment: If you'll find/write a module for it why shouldn't he : )